# Inferring causal effects of partial mediation/moderation

Tags: regression, econometrics, interaction, causality, mediation

I have a manufacturing problem with input variable ***I***, intermediate additive  ***A*** and output ***O***. I have observational data of these variables.

Both ***I*** and ***A*** can impact ***O***, to some extent. Moreover, ***A*** is partly determined by ***I*** in the data I have. That is, based on the input level, additive levels are partly determined (there's a trend), but not fully.

***O*** = f(***I***, ***A***) + error_f,  ***A*** = g(***I***) + error_g.

My goal is to find the effect of ***A*** on ***O***, for different levels of ***I***.

How to frame it in terms of causal analysis? I tried to read about mediators and moderators, but they do not seem to really fit my problem. Also,  it's impossible to perform randomized experiments due to practical reasons, so I am dependent on observational data.

Comment: What kind of scales have your variables?

Comment: they are continuous, positive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the effect of ***A*** on ***O*** at different levels of ***I*** then moderation analysis is what you are looking for. The model would be $O=A+I+A*I+e_O$.

Comment: Thanks. How would this regression equation differ from that for mediation analysis?

Comment: A lot actually. see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/309386/102655 there is a lot of documentation on this topic.